# Metaclass conflict when using celery over flask app

Tags: python, flask, celery

I want to integrate my flask app with celery but I am getting an error :

part of stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/xxxx/PycharmProjects/mp3_to_wav/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 317, in _get_current_object
 return object.__getattribute__(self, '__thing')
AttributeError: 'PromiseProxy' object has no attribute '__thing'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/xxxx/PycharmProjects/mp3_to_wav/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
 raise value
File "/home/xxxx/PycharmProjects/mp3_to_wav/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
 rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/home/xxxx/PycharmProjects/mp3_to_wav/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
 return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/xxxx/PycharmProjects/mp3_to_wav/Tasks/task.py", line 34, in upload_file
 convert.delay(filename, UPLOAD_FOLDER)
File "/home/xxxx/PycharmProjects/mp3_to_wav/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 146, in __getattr__
 return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
File "/home/xxxx/PycharmProjects/mp3_to_wav/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 319, in _get_current_object
 return self.__evaluate__()
File "/home/xxxx/PycharmProjects/mp3_to_wav/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 349, in __evaluate__
 thing = Proxy._get_current_object(self)
File "/home/xxxx/PycharmProjects/mp3_to_wav/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 109, in _get_current_object
 return loc(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/home/xxxx/PycharmProjects/mp3_to_wav/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 451, in _task_from_fun
 '__wrapped__': run}, **options))()
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

and when I try to initiate a celery worker I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '.celery'.
```

celery function:

```
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
      app.import_name,
      backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
      broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask
from Celery import make_celery

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/****'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'amqp://localhost//'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'db+sqlite:///convert.sqlite'

celery = make_celery(app)
```

Then I created a function for celery and used it in flask [POST] request

Comment: can you add the actual stack trace not the error only

Comment: Seems there is more than one exception happening, my guess is that your project structure is not allowing the celery executable to find your app module

Comment: Make sure you can import the module with the app from the directory you're trying to run the command from e.g `from app_module_or_package import app`. Also make sure you don't have a module called `celery.py` as it shadows the one installed.